# Объединение объектов

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть входящие объекты, типа:

```
Object {pos: "test2" , tar : "1"}
Object {pos: "test3" , tar : "2"}
Object {pos: "test4" , tar : "3"}
Object {pos: "test5" , tar : "4"}
```

Нужно объединить в одну строку, что бы получилось test2, test3, test4, test5
Как это правильно сделать?

client:

```
socket.on('infos', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

server:

```
tsRoom.send("clientlist", function(err, response){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    } else {
       response.forEach(function(response) {
        socket.emit('infos', { pos: response.names, tar: response.uid });
    });
}
    });
```

Входящие данные response в цикл:

```
[ { uid: 1,
    names: 'test2',
  { uid: 2,
    names: 'test3',
  { uid: 3,
    names: 'test4',
  { uid: 4,
    names: 'test5' } ]
```

Comment: Входящие данные response мягко говоря не особо валидные

Comment: У Вас в данных сильная нехватка закрывающих скобок "}".

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял: есть массив с объектами, например:

```
var x = [{pos: "test2" , tar : "1"}, {pos: "test3" , tar : "2"}, {pos: "test4" , tar : "3"}, {pos: "test5" , tar : "4"}]
```

Чтобы получить массив ключей pos можно этот массив заманить

```
var out = x.map(function(el) {return el.pos})
```

На выходе будет `[test2, test3, test4, test5]`